# How to add animation when attribute display changes to none?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

How to add anumation in vue app when replacing elements? I want to make it so that when you click on the ,e.g. div with 'Num 1', the divs with class='showing' do not disappear abruptly, but smoothly, for example, go to the side or any other way, is there a way to do so? or with changing classes I won't achieve desired smootheness? 
My code:

```
<template>
  <section class="maps" id="maps" style="">
  
          <div class="showing" :class="{'showingopen':opened1||opened2||opened3||opened4||opened5||opened6||opened7}">
              
              <div class="title py-2 px-2" @click="openpav(1)" :class="{'pav1':opened1}">Num 1</div>
              <div class="title p-2" @click="openpav(2)"  :class="{'pav2':opened2}" >Num 2</div>
              <div class="title p-2" @click="openpav(3)" :class="{'pav3':opened3}">Num 3</div>
              </div>

              <div class="pav1" :class="{'pavopen1':opened1}">
                <div>
                  kldmf
                </div>
                <div>
                  klsfdmn
                </div>  
              </div>
</section>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "maps",
  data() {
    return {
      opened1:false,
      opened2:false,
      opened3:false,}
}
mounted() {
   
  methods: {
openpav(i){
      if (i==1){
        this.opened1 = true
        this.opened2 = false
        this.opened3 = false
      }
      if (i==2){
        this.opened1 = false
        this.opened2 = true
        this.opened3 = false
      }
      if (i==3){
        this.opened1 = false
        this.opened2 = false
        this.opened3 = true
      }

    }
}
}

<style scoped>
.pav1{
  display: none;
}

.pavopen1{
  display: block;
}
.showing{
  display: flex ;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.showingopen{
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot animate an element if you're setting the display to none. Your best best could be to animate opacity and when done, set display to none.

Comment: @Ishettyl can you please clarify how to set display to none only when the opacity is 0? by  watch function? or maybe setInterval which would check every second whether the opacity is 0?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to check when an animation has ended by something like setInterval, you can look for the event animationend.

Here's a simple example where the div goes to opacity: 0 over 10 seconds and then the display gets set to none.

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');
div.addEventListener('animationend', function () {div.style.display='none';animation=''; });
```

```css
div {
  animation: fade 10s 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }
@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>hello</div>
```